# How to unit test a php class constructor that returns no value

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, codeception

I'm a little bit confused about how to unit test a constructor, particularly since it returns no value.

Let's assume I have this class:

```
class MyClass {

    /** @var array */
    public $registered_items;

    /**
     * Register all of the items upon instantiation
     *
     * @param  array  $myArrayOfItems  an array of objects
     */
    public function __construct($myArrayOfItems) {
        foreach($myArrayOfItems as $myItem) {
            $this->registerItem($myItem);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register a single item
     *
     * @param  object  $item  a single item with properties 'slug' and 'data'
     */
    private function registerItem($item) {
        $this->registered_items[$item->slug] = $item->data; 
    }

}
```

Obviously this is a bit contrived and incredibly simple, but it's for the sake of the question. =)

So yeah, how would I go about writing a unit test for the constructor here?

Bonus question: am I right in thinking that no unit test for `registerItem()` would be needed in a case such as this?

### EDIT

How about if I re-factored to remove the logic from the constructor. How would I test `registerItem()` in this case?

```
class MyClass {

    /** @var array */
    public $registered_items;

    public function __construct() {
        // Nothing at the moment
    }

    /**
     * Register all of the items
     *
     * @param  array  $myArrayOfItems  an array of objects
     */
    public function registerItem($myArrayOfItems) {
        foreach($myArrayOfItems as $item) {
            $this->registered_items[$item->slug] = $item->data;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: A class constructor instantiates an object, so you can test that an object of the right type has been successfully created; but it is generally considered bad practise to have any significant code in the constructor

Comment: Thanks Mark! How about if I re-factored as shown above?

Comment: You'd still test object instantiation the same way, testing for the successful creation of an object of the right type; but it's probably also worth making your `registerItem()` method public (so it can be tested) and creating a public method to retrieve registered items, so you can also test those elements of your code

Comment: Ah yes, I meant to make `registerItems()` public in that refactor. Typo, haha.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**For First Code**

```
public function testConstruct{
    $arrayOfItems = your array;

    $myClass = new MyClass($arrayOfItems);

    foreach($arrayOfItems as $myItem) {
       $expected_registered_items[$item->slug] = $item->data;
    }

    $this->assertEquals($expected_registered_items, $myClass->registered_items);
}
```

Comment: Is it considered bad practice to look at `$myClass->registered_items` since it's not technically part of the method I'm testing?

Comment: Also, in the refactored code it was meant to be `public` :-| . I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to look up a registered item.

```
class MyClass {
    ...

    /**
     * Returns a registered item
     *
     * @param string $slug unique slug of the item to retrieve
     * @return object the matching registered item or null
     */
    public function getRegisteredItem($slug) {
        return isset($this->registered_items[$slug]) ? $this->registered_items[$slug] : null;
    }
}
```

Then check that each item passed to the constructor in the test has been registered.

```
class MyClassTest {
    public function testConstructorRegistersItems() {
        $item = new Item('slug');
        $fixture = new MyClass(array($item));
        assertThat($fixture->getRegisteredItem('slug'), identicalTo($item));
    }
}
```

Note: I'm using the [Hamcrest assertions](https://github.com/hamcrest/hamcrest-php), but PHPUnit should have an equivalent.